# Cardinality of a Galois Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4 \in \mathbb{C}$ be the roots of $T^4 - 2 \in \mathbb{Q}[T]$ and let $E$ be the field $\mathbb{Q}(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4)$. Now consider the group $G = \text{Gal}(E / \mathbb{Q})$, the Galois group of $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I am trying to show that the cardinality of $G$ is 8. I am having a hard time getting started with this.

My first thought is to try to find an element $g \in G$ of order 4 and also find an element $h \in G$ of order 2 that is not in $\langle g \rangle$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes sorry it should be $T^4$

Comment: Can you prove that $[E:\Bbb{Q}]=8$? This immediately gives you the order of the Galois group (assuming key pieces of theory have been covered). It is also possible to get the order in the manner you described, so my suggestion is by no means the only way. To give you a useful answer we do need to know what relations between $|G|$ and $[E:\Bbb{Q}]$ have been explained to you up to this point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$G$ has subgroups $K = \text{Gal}(E / \mathbb{Q}(i))$ and $H = \text{Gal}(E / \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})).$ We define $g \in K$ by $g(\sqrt[4]{2}) = i\sqrt[4]{2}$ and define $h \in H$ by $h(i) = -i$ (the restriction of complex conjugation). Then $g$ has order 4 and $h$ has order $2$. Since $K \cap H = 1$, it follows that $|G| \geq 8$. Since $[E : \mathbb{Q}] = 8$ we must have that $|G| = 8$ generated by $g$ and $h$.

Moreover, to really drive this home, we have that $$hgh^{-1}(\sqrt[4]{2}) = -i\sqrt[4]{2} = g^{-1}(\sqrt[4]{2})$$
and
$$hgh^{-1}(i) = i = g^{-1}(i)$$
Hence $hgh^{-1} = g^{-1}$. Thus this tells us that $G \cong D_4$. As we know $|D_4| = 8.$